# Similarity and/or Diff of two ODT documents (Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, diff, odt

I have two ODT documents, they have very close contents, I want to compare them to see how similar they are.

The best would be to have a **similarity percentage**, if not possible, an alternative would be at least to have some sort of ***diff***.

I am running *Ubuntu Lucid*.

---

**Solution:**

I used `odt2txt` to convert the files to text, then used `wdiff -i --statistics one.txt two.txt` to have a diff along with statistics which gave me the percentage of common words (similarity).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do a binary diff on two identically sized files under linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/135911/how-do-a-binary-diff-on-two-identically-sized-files-under-linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried them myself but [this pair of tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20140715162315/http://www.t3node.com/blog/creating-a-diff-of-openoffice-odt-documents-on-the-command-line/) - odt2txt and oodiff - looks promising.

Comment: I used odt2txt to convert them to text, and then used wdiff which gives a diff by word.

Comment: Thanks.  This is great for use in version control systems like git or mercurial.  See integration / automation techniques at [OpenDocument, diff, and revision-control](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~moy/opendocument/)

Answer (score 26):

Did you try the built-in compare functionality? *Edit -> Track Changes -> Compare Document...*.

If you just want a textual diff, your best bet is probably to convert both documents to plain text, then run a regular diff on them. You will have to figure out how to normalize linebreaks though, otherwise the diff will not be very useful.

Comment: Great function in LibreOffice, I had never heard about it! Very useful but no stats are given.

Comment: Excellent!  I never would have thought to look in an *Edit* menu to compare documents.  I looked in *File*, *Tools*, and *Window*, the last being uSoft's Word location.

Comment: In the latest version it seems to be Edit -> Track Changes -> Compare Document...

Comment: @FableBlaze: Thanks, edited (though it took me a while...).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about text formatting, you may as well copy the contents to plaintext files and use good old diff.

ps: Are you a teacher looking for possible cheaters ? :p

Comment: lol no I'm not a teacher but yeah this would be a good way to look for cheaters :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to produce .pdf files with libreoffice and then use diffpdf to compare the two pdf files.
This shows the differences highlighted in parallel windows